Need help installing dpkg and apt without a package manager on opentom
So I'm trying to install a package manager (dpkg and apt) on a TomTom device running Linux that uses OpenTom. There is not a lot of documentation on this and there is no other type of thing that I could find. It reports a version of "Linux 2.6.13" if that helps. Thanks!
I tried to install it by copying the from another Linux distro and it made a weird file and it did not work. I looked online a lot and found some issues describing it, but none of them worked.

that sadly doesn't make too much sense – assuming you have the necessary libraries to install either of these package managers, which packets would you then install? You'd basically need to port a complete distro, not just the package manager, to your target device. And seeing that your device's kernel is from mid-2005, I'd assume that that's going to be quite a challenge, with little return on investment for a device that's probably very slow by modern standards.

But your system already has a linux distribution, OpenTom, so use that instead of trying to use the package managers from other distros.

Just in case it wasn't clear - just getting a package manager to work doesn't mean you'll automatically be able to use some random disto's packages on top of the one on you have. You'll basically run into the problem of dependency hell all over again.

@MarcusMüller the problem with that is that there was no package manager

@muru but having a package manager doesn't help you at all – there's no packages that would be compatible with your platform that you could install through that.
